# Where do I need to go to find the Khazra Staff?

Tags: diablo-iii

I have the objective 'Find the Khazra Staff' in the quest 'Trailing the Coven'. I'm in New Tristram, and I have no idea where I'm supposed to be going!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to be on the lookout for a cart called "Karyna's Lost Wagon," somewhere in the Southern Highlands. When you find it, click on it to receive the Khazra Staff.

Answer (score 0):

The last place you can teleport to , go there and find a wagon with a staff on it

Answer (score -1):

to the right of the path you will find a little tiny path, go down it and you will find her wagon, pick up up the staff off of her wagon and you did it B-)

Comment: It's a random location in the Highlands.